# Google map api v3 multiple markers - problem with scrollbar and infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to make a map with around 200 markers and for each marker an infowindow. 
I tested it with two markers. 
This is the site: http://www.bau-berater-kdr.de/pages/bauberater-karte.php

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head> 

<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 650px; height: 550px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['Koehn, Andrej<br>Dipl. Ing. Architektur<br>', 52.5299, 13.4149, 2],
  ['List, Walter, Dipl. Ing. (FH)<br>Büro für Baubiologie u. Grundstücksbewertung<br><a href="http://www.Baubiologie-Mitteldeutschland.de">www.Baubiologie-Mitteldeutschland.de</a>', 51.4233, 12.2992, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5299, 13.4149),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
</script>
</body>
```

There is one main problem and I didn't found a solution: 
When you click on a marker you will see 2 vertical scrollbars.. only need one and I thought the window would auto-size. Would like to increase the height. Does anyone know a solution?

And if anybody knows how to make this easier for such an amount of markers, I would be deeply grateful!

Comment: strange i copy and paste your code into a http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/RTPrf/ and seems fine.  you might have modified something with your css

Comment: thanks for the quick answer... mmh strange .. dont know where to look for in the css files... puh.. any idea?

Comment: can't really tell without seeing your css

Comment: https://sfm.hidrive.strato.com/lnk/1DlDnAA8
https://sfm.hidrive.strato.com/lnk/VLlDncNf
https://sfm.hidrive.strato.com/lnk/0elDn6b3
i would very appreciate if you could look into it 
for english info for the download please klick sprache and choose english

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/RTPrf/ you've modified the google map infowindow's css, but i do not see much difference

Comment: when i remove the div with width and height the hole map is not visible anymore..thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

[Handling Large Amounts of Markers in Google Maps](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps)

I've had success using the MarkerClusterer option on a map with several thousand markers.